# I run Tomcat 9 and it keeps saying: GRAVE: A child container failed during start

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Spring_MVC_DinamicWebPages]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:738)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Spring_MVC_DinamicWebPages]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2260)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2218)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5044)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 27 more

jul 19, 2020 10:25:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:738)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Spring_MVC_DinamicWebPages]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Spring_MVC_DinamicWebPages]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2260)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2218)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5044)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 27 more

jul 19, 2020 10:25:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: Tomcat no puede iniciar porque el componente Server requerido fallo al iniciar.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:738)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Spring_MVC_DinamicWebPages]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Spring_MVC_DinamicWebPages]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2260)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2218)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5044)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 27 more

jul 19, 2020 10:25:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMACIÓN: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
jul 19, 2020 10:25:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Parando servicio [Catalina]
jul 19, 2020 10:25:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMACIÓN: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

This is the fatal error I get. I´ve tried and reinstalled eclipse as well as Tomcat, but it doesn´t work.

Comment: Rest in Peace..

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right there in the stack trace:

`More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.`

You have multiple JARs in WEB-INF/lib (and in $possibly $CATALINA_BASE/lib depending on configuration) that have a contain a `META-INF/web-fragment.xml` that declares a name of `spring_web`. That isn't legal so Tomcat refuses to start the app.

Most likely you have multiple versions and/or copies of one or more Spring JARs. Ensure you only have a single and the app will start (or at least get further before it fails for some other reason).

Comment: Hi Mr. Mark Thomas. I´ve had a look at the libraries and at most are everyone with its different name. I¨m a newbie, may I be doing something wrong? Thank you in advance